# building an XML service parsing library

Tags: java, xml, web-services, parsing

This is more of a design question I suppose. My company offers a web service to our client that spits data out in a custom xml format. I'd like to build a java library we can offer so our customers can just feed it the url and we will turn it into a set of POJOs built from the response.

I can obviously just create a library that will do some simple xml parsing and building of the POJOs but I'm looking to build something a bit more robust.

My brain is pulling me in a million directions, wondering if anyone has some pointers or some code to poke at. Was thinking about adding an Abdera extension, but it's not really a syndication format that fits the Abdera model. And most of the popular service libraries (twitter, facebook) all rely on standards format parsers, of which our format isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with JAXB?

here is the tutorial: https://jaxb.dev.java.net/tutorial/